# Why the code would be at risk for seeing a partially constructed object?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile

There is an [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp06197/) about volatile using in ibm,and the explanation confused me,below is a sample in this article and its explanation:

```
public class BackgroundFloobleLoader {
    public volatile Flooble theFlooble;

    public void initInBackground() {
        // do lots of stuff
        theFlooble = new Flooble();  // this is the only write to theFlooble
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass {
    public void doWork() {
        while (true) { 
            // do some stuff...
            // use the Flooble, but only if it is ready
            if (floobleLoader.theFlooble != null) 
                doSomething(floobleLoader.theFlooble);
        }
    }
}
```

> Without the theFlooble reference being volatile, the code in doWork() would be at risk for seeing a partially constructed Flooble as it dereferences the theFlooble reference.

How to understand this?Why without volatile,we may use a partially constructed `Flooble` object?Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the `volatile` you could see a partially constructed object. E.g. consider this `Flooble` object.

```
public class Flooble {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Flooble() {
       x = 5;
       y = 1;
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass {
    public void doWork() {
    while (true) { 
        // do some stuff...
        // use the Flooble, but only if it is ready
        if (floobleLoader.theFlooble != null) 
            doSomething(floobleLoader.theFlooble);
    }

    public void doSomething(Flooble flooble) {
        System.out.println(flooble.x / flooble.y);
    }
}
```

}

Without `volatile` the method doSomething is not guaranteed to see the values `5` and `1` for `x` and `y`. It could see for instance `x == 5` but `y == 0`, leading to division by zero.

When you execute this operation `theFlooble = new Flooble()`, three writes occur:

1. `tmpFlooble.x = 5`
2. `tmpFlooble.y = 1`
3. `theFlooble = tmpFlooble`

If these writes happen in this order everything is ok. But without the `volatile` the compiler is free to reorder these writes and perform them as it wishes. E.g. first point 3 and then points 1 and 2.

This actually happens all the time. The compiler really does reorder the writes. This is done to increase performance.

The error can easily happen in the following way:

Thread `A` executes `initInBackground()` method from class `BackgroundFloobleLoader`. The compiler reorders the writes so before executing the body of `Flooble()` (where `x` and `y` are set), the thread `A` first executes `theFlooble = new Flooble()`. Now, `theFlooble` points to a flooble instance, whose `x` and `y` are `0`. Before thread `A` continues, some other thread `B` executes method `doWork()` of class `SomeOtherClass`. This method calls method `doSomething(floobleLoader.theFlooble)` with the current value of `theFlooble`. In this method `theFlooble.x` is divided by `theFlooble.y` resulting in division by zero. Thread `B` finishes due to uncaught exception. Thread `A` continues and sets `theFlooble.x = 5` and `theFlooble.y = 1`.

This scenario of course won't happen on every run, but according to the rules of Java, *can* happen.

Comment: @FireSun Please see the edit. Does it answer your question?

Comment: sorry,can you complete the code in question to show the case where the error will happen clearly.

Comment: @FireSun That's totally the wrong way to think about this. The right way to think about this is "I need a guarantee I don't have". The wrong way to think about it is "can I think of a way this can fail". Code can fail in ways that nobody could think of at the time the code was written. If you need a guarantee you don't have, the code is broken whether or not anyone can think of a way it can fail. The next version of the run time, the next library, the next CPU, the next OS may have ways it can fail that nobody can think of today.

Answer (score 0):

When different threads access your code, any thread can perform modifications on the state of your object, which means that when other threads access it, the state may not be as it should.

From the oracle documentation:

> The Java programming language allows threads to access shared
>   variables. As a rule, to ensure that shared variables are
>   consistently and reliably updated, a thread should ensure that it has
>   exclusive use of such variables by obtaining a lock that,
>   conventionally, enforces mutual exclusion for those shared variables.
>
> The Java programming language provides a second mechanism, volatile
>   fields, that is more convenient than locking for some purposes.
>
> A field may be declared volatile, in which case the Java Memory Model
>   ensures that all threads see a consistent value for the variable.

[source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4)

Which means the value of this variable will never be cached thread-locally, all reads and writes will go straight to "main memory"

For example picture thread1 and thread2 accessing the object:

1. Thread1 access the object and stores it in its local cache
2. Trhead2 modifies the object
3. Thread1 accesses the object again, but since it is still in its cache, it doesn't access the updated state by thread2.

Comment: thank you for the answer,do you mean the "partially constructed object" means it maybe a expired value?

Comment: it could, because of the local cache of each thread, i'll update the answer.

Comment: @Saljuama, should it be the reference of the object that is subject to caching in threads? If the variable was of primitive type, then the threads would be caching the values.

Comment: good point @IzCe, i'll research some and update my answer accordingly soon

Answer (score 0):

Look at it from the point of view of the code that does this:

```
        if (floobleLoader.theFlooble != null) 
            doSomething(floobleLoader.theFlooble);
```

Clearly, you need a guarantee that all of the writes performed by `new Flooble()` are visible to this code before `theFlooble` could possibly test as `!= null`. Nothing in the code without `volatile` provides this guarantee. So you need a guarantee you don't have. Fail.

Java provides several ways to get the guarantee you need. One is by use of a `volatile` variable:

> ... any write to a volatile variable establishes a happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same variable. This means that changes to a volatile variable are always visible to other threads. What's more, it also means that when a thread reads a volatile variable, it sees not just the latest change to the volatile, but also the side effects of the code that led up the change. -- [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html)

So putting a write to a `volatile` in one thread and a read to a `volatile` in the other establishes precisely the happens-before relationship we need.

Answer (score -2):

I doubt there is such a thing as partially constructed objects in Java. Volatile guarantees that every thread will see a constructed object. Since volatile works like a tiny synchronized block on the referenced object you would end up with a NPE if `theFlobble == null`. Maybe that is what they mean.

Comment: thank you for the answer,when the NPE will exists if no `volatile`?

Answer (score -2):

Objects encapsulate a lot of things: variables, methods, etc. and these take time to come into existence inside a computer. In Java, if any variable is declared volatile then all reads and writes to it is atomic. So if a variable referencing an object is declared volatile then access to its members is allowed only when it fully loads in your system (how do you read or write to something that isn't there at all?)

Comment: thank you for the answer,the last word "how do you read or write to something that isn't there at all?",what does it mean?I can't understand well,please explain more clearly.thanks again.

Comment: This answer is totally wrong. The `volatile` keyword has nothing to do with atomicity that is relevant to this question. It has to do with ordering and visibility.

Comment: nothing to do with atomicity? well what I learnt was reads and writes to volatile variables are atomic. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html